# How to define Unknown Section name

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am working on a editor application, desktop, that will take in a JSON file, allow editing and saving the edited JSON back to the file.

In reviewing some of these files, i noticed various similarities in structure.

1. [0] index is similar to a spreadsheets column definition
2. [1]+ indexes are the data associated with the columns defined in index 0

From what i have derived from the content, this information is probably an output of database content.  The structure is very consistent to what you might build from a spreadsheet table, almost like a Pivot table.

### Question:

How do i build a schema structure where i do not know the `property` or `item` name but i do know the content structure.

### Basic Structure:

```
{
    "item1":[{
        "col1":[<idx>, <datatype>],
        "col2":[<idx>, <datatype>],
        ....
        "col-n":[<idx>, <datatype>]
    },{
        "name1":[<val1>],
        "name2":[<val2>],
        ....
        "name-n":[<val-n>]
    }],
    "item2":[{
        ....
    }],
    ....
    "item-n":[{
        ....
    }]
}
```

### Problems:

1. "item1", "item2", up to "item-n" are not standard names.  They can change from file to file.  The underlying structure of the Array is the same just not the name.
2. "col1", "col2", up to "col-n" follow the same rules as #1.  The actual value that would represent `key` in the key-value pair is never the same from file to file.

### Current Schema

I know it is sad newbie development so far.  Yes its not much, but did not see any information about Generic definition for property names, `key`.

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "idx_dt":{
            "type":"array",
            "items": [{
                "type":"integer",
            },{
                "type":"integer"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically a pseudo-type definition for the `col1`, `col2`, up to `col-n` definition

The thought being I could simply define the columns as that type.

Everything I tried failed badly for validating the file contents.  I am obviously doing something severely bad.

I have tried using the Schema Creators online but they all hard-code the names of the top-level items.  I need them to be identified but not strictly defined.

Comment: What language are you writing your editor in?  You could simply use the foreach operator in the language to cycle through each level.

Comment: c# will be the language.  Figured it would "easier" to just build a validator.  I have roughly 20-30 files that have the same type structure.  As well, trying to load the content into a JSON.Net object (JToken, JObject, JArray, etc) to then read off of it.

Comment: You may use patternProperties to provide constraints to items keys and specify the schema. If there is no constraint on items keys, you can use additionalProperties, that allows you to specify the schema for not defined properties.

Comment: I will have to read up on those.  For now I have put it into a b*st*rdized form of .Net validation.  Not efficient for validation but works, for the moment.  At least I can continue on through the development ;(